# Pulling last month of last year using SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new here and fairly new to SQL so I apologize if this has been addressed elsewhere.  Any guidance/help is very much appreciated.

I have the following SQL statement that was working last month, but since we started the new year, it has stopped working.  I have tried using `DATEADD` but it still didn't seem to pull the previous month/year content:

```
$votes  = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$GLOBALS['votes']." 
         WHERE vote_yymm BETWEEN '".(date("ym")-1)."' AND '".date("ym")."'
     ORDER BY vote_yymm DESC LIMIT ".$start.", ".$count);
```

Comment: It seems to me the problem isn't MySQL but the (php?) functions you are using to populate the Query.

Comment: Thats because `date('ym')` returns `1601` and `1601` minus 1 is `1600` and that is not a valid `ym`

Comment: yes, sorry, it is the PHP functions causing my issues.

Comment: use `(date("m")-1 == "01" ? (date("y")-1)."12" : (date("ym")-1))` instead of `(date("ym")-1)`

Comment: I would not mix such functions php date + mysql, let it be done by the database itself. It would be `between (now() - interval 1 month)  and now()`

Comment: @JorgeCampos Write that up as an answer and you would get my upvote.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks! I did not add it as an answer because I realize that the OP's database has a bad design because the field is not defined as date but as integer or worse string, since he is trying to format the dates YYYYMM and subtract 1 from it!! But thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use some calculation the will be able to cope with correct date subtraction.

Replace your `date("ym")-1` with

```
date('ym', strtotime('-1 month'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Riggs!  That did the trick.  Very much appreciated.

Comment: You are more than welcome. Although I have to admit @JorgeCampos made a good point about doing this calculation all in SQL Syntax

Comment: ok, sounds good.  I appreciate it as well as @JorgeCampos response.